# Footnotemark inside itemize

Tags: footnotes, itemize

I am trying to put a `\footonotemark[ ]` inside an itemize environment.

But when I compile, instead of having the footnote superscript I have the number of the footonote between brackets.

For example:

```
\begin{itemize}
\item bla bla bla\foonotemark[14]
\end {itemize}
```

appears as:

- bla bla bla[14]

The command is working properly if I use it outside the environment.

Comment: Show a complete example.

Comment: What's the purpose of `\footnotemark` inside `itemize`? The standard `\footnote` should work.

Comment: It was to make the text more readable (for me) when written. But I will go with \footnote since it is woking. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps your problem is that you mistyped `\footnotemark` as `\foonotemark`? Works just fine for me in the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
bla bla bla\footnotemark[13] 
\begin{itemize} 
    \item bla bla bla\footnotemark[14] 
    \item bla bla bla\foonotemark[15] 
    \item bla bla bla\footnote[16]{usual footnote works too}
\end {itemize}
\footnotetext[13]{works here}
\footnotetext[14]{and here}
\footnotetext[15]{but not here}
\end{document}
```

Also, as egreg suggested, you could simply use the usual `\footnote` with optional argument in `[]`, as I do in `[16]`

Comment: That is exactly the problem. Thanks!!. Sorry for taking your time for that . Most of times the error is just in front of you but you dont see it ;)   Thanks!

Comment: @Andrus, No problem. By the way, if you use [overleaf](http://v2.overleaf.com) then you should be able to see the compile errors in the logs. Yours gets smth like ```l.9     \item bla bla bla\foonotemark
                                     [15]
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never defined.```, pretty readable. Actually, if you compile your files via pdflatex (or alike command) you should be able to the the compile error as well, it just can be not that clearly formatted.